# Inserting ASP.NET button into jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, events, postback

Does anyone know of a method where it would be possible to insert a ASP.NET button (IE: A button with a `runat="server"` tag) into a jQuery UI Dialog (specifically the area where the buttons are contained)?

Obviously the point of this is so I can handle the click event serverside from these buttons. I am aware that I could cause a postback from the dialog buttons by handling the click event and triggering the `__DoPostBack` method

Example:

```
$("#MyDialogDiv").dialog({
    height: 400,
    width: 450,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok : function () {
            __DoPostBack(eventTarget, eventArguments);
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }, Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

However am hoping to achieve a more elegant solution where I could still declaratively add the buttons to the dialog but they would be inserted into the dialog button area.

Unfortunately the only way I can think of is basically rewriting the entire dialog create method structure but perhaps there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id love to hear suggestions but it seems this might be the only simple "mostly generic" method to do this. Hacky but it works...

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.CustomDialog = function (options) {
        this.dialog(options)
            .parent()
            .find(".ui-dialog-buttonpane > .ui-dialog-buttonset")
            .append($(".DialogButton").button());
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add server button in markup, hide it with `display:none` style and use `__doPostBack('<%= ButtonID.ClientID %>', '')` script for Ok dialog button

Comment: Yeah thats a fair option but seems about as hacky as the alternative and requires a hidden button for each "real" button.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to insert it into the dialog at all. jQuery UI dialog acts on a container when you call `.dialog()`. So in your example, you just need your form elements including your  `<asp:button />` in you `<div id="MyDialogDiv">` and then call `.dialog()` on it. Note: In my experience there can be a little more to it than I've outlined e.g. you may need to append the dialog to the form on open as jQuery UI pulls it out of its place in the DOM.